# Multicast to directly connected WIFI device

Tags: java, camera, udp, multicast, sony

I have a WIFI device, that I am experimenting with. From my macbook I can make a direct connection to the device over wifi. After I have WIFI connection I should be able to communicate with the device over multicast.
However, as soon as I try to send a datagram packet to the camera when I am connected I get some IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't assign requested address
```

I reviewed some networking settings and found out that Multicast is enabled for my laptop, also I added the multicast address that is used (239.255.255.250) to the routing table. (Read this somewhere) Still no luck...

Why do I get this exception from my application?

Here is the code I use to connect:

```
DatagramSocket socket = null;
DatagramPacket packet = null;
try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetSocketAddress iAddress = new InetSocketAddress("239.255.255.250", 1900);
    packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,iAddress);
    socket.send(packet);
```

I think it has something to do with my network / setup. 
When I reconnect to my wireless acces point, my app doesn't give this exception and I can see the package in my console:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Roy:~ Roy$ sudo tcpdump -ni en1 host 239.255.255.250
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
19:54:18.688367 IP 192.168.1.34.57428 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 129
19:54:18.789447 IP 192.168.1.34.57428 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 129
19:54:18.890506 IP 192.168.1.34.57428 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 129
```

Answer (score 0):

`InetSocketAddress` is not a `InetAddress` (it's a `SocketAddress`). You probably want something like this:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250");
packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, addr, 1900);
socket.send(packet);
```

Comment: I don't think it's got anything to do with my code. Your snippet gives me the same exception. See additional info in my recent edits.

Any ideas on how to debug this?